# Как передать html кол в url , для того, чтобы скачать?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, tcpdf

У меня есть скрипт, который генерирует пдф файл из гет/пост запроса.

```html
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 006', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// writeHTML($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='')
// writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true)

// create some HTML content


// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');









//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output($title, 'I');
```

Я пытаюсь отправить при клике на ссылку код html страницы, 
у меня не отправляется...

```js
$(document).on("click",".download_files li a",function(event){
        var html=$(".contents.con").html();
        var title = $("h1").html();
     window.location="/ajax_new/save_page_pdf.php?html="+html+"&title="+title;
    });
```

Если же отправить `window.location="/ajax_new/save_page_pdf.php?html=123&title="+title;`

то генерируется pdf в новом окне.

Вопрос, как передать html код в url , для того, чтобы скачать? html может быть большой.
или путем аякса? у меня никак...

```js
 $(".download_files li a").click(function(e){
       var data={};
       data["type"]=$(this).attr("data-doc");
       data["html"]=$(".contents.con").html();
       html=$(".contents.con").html();
       if ($("h1").length>0) {
           data["title"] = $("h1").html();
       }else{
           if ($(".h1").length>0)
                data["title"]=$(".h1").html();
       }

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax_new/save_page_pdf.php",
            data: data,
            success: download.bind(true, "title.pdf", "html")
                function(data1) {
                var blob=new Blob([data1]);
                var link=document.createElement('a');
                link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download=data["title"]+".pdf";
                link.click();
            }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click",".download_files li a",function(event){
        var html=encodeURIComponent($(".contents.con").html());
        var title = encodeURIComponent($("h1").html());
     window.location="/ajax_new/save_page_pdf.php?html="+html+"&title="+title;
    });
```

PHP:

```
$html = urldecode($html);
$title = urldecode($title);
```